# .NET connection to SAP RFC table

Tags: c#, .net, saprfc

I am not a SAP expert, but need to get a project up and running as quickly as possible and need some advise.

We have a .Net project (C#) that uses VS 2019 Professional and we need to pull data from a Kafka topic and insert it into a RFC table in SAP. Pulling the data from Kafka is not an issue. However connecting to SAP and inserting the data we are unsure how to configure the project to do it.

It looks like we need to use the [SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK 7.50 - SAP Support Portal](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/nwrfcsdk.html) as the connector. We have downloaded the 64 bit connector for Windows and it is a set of .dll files - there is no install program.

My question is, is this the correct connector to use and how do we configure the .Net project to use this connector. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We tried to place the dlls in the windows system SYSWOW64 and also in a bin directory in the project, but it throws an error that the DLLs cannot be found.

Comment: Note that you also have the SAP .NET Connector which is also based on RFC protocol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Step by step tutorial to use SAP. net Connector with VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300049/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-sap-net-connector-with-vs-2008)

Comment: check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356205/can-you-use-visual-studio-2017-with-the-sap-net-connector-3-0/51357706#51357706

Comment: @Sandra - we saw the SAP .Net Connector. For our project we are only allowed to use the NetWeaver Connector.

Comment: @Suncatcher, those articles are not for the VS version and adaptor that we want to use. We have however made progress by adding the DLLs to the bin dir in the project and we can now connect. It looks like we will need to put them on the SAP path if we deploy to production.